# How to adjust render depth in Haskell's OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, haskell, glfw

I'm trying to get some objects rendering in 3D space in Haskell with OpenGL. I can't figure out how to render shapes in the Z-dimension, though. Adjusting the values for the triangle's points causes it to not render. (Is there an equivalent for `glEnable` that I'm missing to set up the depth buffer?)

Here's the code (edited for brevity):

```
initGL :: IO ()
initGL = do
            shadeModel $= Smooth
            clearDepth $= 1
            depthFunc $= Just Lequal
            hint PerspectiveCorrection $= Nicest

drawFrame :: WindowRefreshCallback
drawFrame = do
               clear [ ColorBuffer, DepthBuffer ]
               loadIdentity

               renderPrimitive Triangles $ foldl1' (>>) $ map vertex
                   [ Vertex3 0      1  0 -- top
                   , Vertex3 1    (-1) 0 -- bottom right
                   , Vertex3 (-1) (-1) (0 :: GLdouble) -- bottom left
                   ]   

               flush

main :: IO()
main = do
          True <- initialize
          True <- openWindow (Size 800 600) [] Window 

          ... -- Set window title, set up callbacks

          initGL
          clearColor $= toGLColor (Color4 0 175 200 0)

          doWhile (not <$> readIORef isClosed) $ drawFrame >> swapBuffers
```

Comment: Did you change any transformation matrix?

Comment: I tried some code with `translate`, but it did nothing (w.r.t. Z-axis) for |Z| <= 1, and didn't render for |Z| > 1

Other than that, only the call to `loadIdentity` affects the matrix (AFAIK)

Comment: Without any modification the matrices will be unit matrices. So the range of your viewing frustum on the z axis will lie between 0 and -1 (the camera is looking down from the coordinate origin along the negative z axis).

Comment: Regarding your other question: In C one could write `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);` (I do not know the Haskell equivalent), but this will only enable the test if a new fragment is occluding another. So if nothing was drawn up to now and your depth buffer is cleared, it should not matter if the depth test is enabled or not.

Comment: Thanks! Adding a `Graphics.Rendering.OpenGL.GLU.Matrix.perspective` call fixed it!
If you post an actual answer, I can mark this as answered.

Comment: @Nobody: Z range is 0…1 in NDC, however NDC Z is obtained by mapping the post transformation Z range -1…1 to 0…1, so the visible Z range with identity matrices is -1…1 (to match with the rest of the limts, so the post transformation clip volume is [-1…1]^3

Comment: @datenwolf Sry for the mistake, my hands were faster than my mind ^^ Fortunately there are enough people here to correct these. Unfortunately I cannot edit the post to remove the error (to prevent the error from spreading)

Answer (score 1):

This is what I do to set up a window. I'm using GLUT to set things up.

```
main = do
  (progName, _) <- getArgsAndInitialize
  initialDisplayMode $= [DoubleBuffered, WithDepthBuffer]
  createWindow progName
  windowSize $= Size 640 480
  <...code omitted...>
```

The line you're possibly after is the third line which sets up a window `WithDepthBuffer`